# Weird results from: Create table .. as select from

Tags: sql, teradata, create-table, teradata-sql-assistant

Could it be that the following query gives weird results (without errors):

```
 CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE 
 AS ( 
  SELECT COL_1, COL2 
  FROM EXISTING_TABLE_1
  UNION
  SELECT COL_1, COL2 
  FROM EXISTING_TABLE_2

  WHERE key_id NOT IN (

                        SELECT key_id 
                        FROM(
                               SELECT COL1, COL2
                               FROM EXISTING_TABLE_3
                               UNION 
                               SELECT COL1, COL2
                               FROM EXISTING_TABLE_4
                                  )A
    )
 ) WITH DATA
```

When I run similar code, but with real table names and data, my table has for example 250K records. While, when I just run the `select` part, so everything between the brackets, I get 300K + records.

Is `create table .... as ( select .... ) WITH DATA` known for problems like this?

FYI: I don't get any errors, I noticed this a little late when doing analysis.

Comment: "my table has 250K records" but you're unioning two selects from different tables..

Comment: Do you actually use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Hi, I am using UNION. And I was probably not clear: what I meant is that I run the whole part from: `SELECT col1, ..... FROM EXISTING_TABLE_4) A  )` --> gives around 300K records. But the created table gives around 250K. Shouldn't these two be exactly the same always?

Comment: That's why I was asking if you actually use UNION. When you do a SHOW TABLE you will probably notice that the table was created as a SET TABLE which automatically removes *duplicate rows*, but UNION is also DISTINCT and then both should result in the same number of rows. Can you compare both Explains to check if they differ?

Comment: `SHOW TABLE` indeed tells me it was created as a `SET TABLE`, as you suggested. Whether I use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` doesn't make a difference in my select it seems.

Comment: Compare the CREATE and the SELECT Explains if they differ, e.g. one has a "sorted eliminating duplicate rows" or an "aggregated" which is missing in the other (then you might have found a bug). Or Insert the result of your Select into the table and do a `select col1,col2 from tab group by 1,2 having count(*) > 1` if there a duplicates.